# how many cells to commence with in a UICollectionView for a Calendar? (i.e. with infinite number of dates)

Tags: ios, calendar, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How many cells to commence with in a UICollectionView for a Calendar?  That is my understanding is:

1. UICollectionView is good in that it only instantiates cells it
   needs to display, but then
2. You still have to add the cells to the collection view

So what is best practice if say your view would only show 10 cells, but you had unlimited cells (e.g. scrolling up and down dates in a calendar). Do you enter say 100 cells for 100 dates (say 50 either side of the starting date of interest) and then manually keep track of when you get to one of these edges and then add more?   This would kind of be ashame the UICollectionView framework couldn't keep track of this itself no?

So overall questions therefore (sorry) are really:

1. How many cells (dates) should you be creating in the collectionview.  Should it be limited therefore to say 100
2. Is there no support in UICollectionView to automate adding more cells in for you for a Calendar type situation where dates are endless if the user wants to keep scrolling forward or backward
3. Any what is impact on the caching strategy for UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes too?

Comment: For calendar, I used `UIScrollView` and manage the items by hand. ("Intima" app in apple store)

Comment: I'm looking at a vertical scrolling calendar, one week across a row (7 cells), then ability to scroll up/down.  How would you handle the fact a user may want to scroll a couple of years forward however, so say ~100 rows in this case?  Or do you just draw it as one big static view and not worry about only instantiating cells as they become visible?

Comment: You should install "Intima" in Apple store to see what I have done if you have time :) . I created 5 months, 1month have 30days, each day is a custom view. And manage them by hand, like: add, remove, reuse, ... I just use `UIScrollView`

Comment: For calendar,I used a cell for the month view.It's smooth than a cell for the day view.
In order to display from 1970 to 2099 ， add (2099 - 1970)*12 month cells.

Comment: @haiLong - is there much overhead/performance impact in allocating so many however?   I guess it doesn't render the cells, however it would just be the calculation and storage of the layoutAttributes for all these I guess?

Comment: @Greg it’s perform well.in my case. 

There only two instance of UICollectionViewCell.
I have write a horizontal scrolling calendar . 
A  UICollectionViewCell as a month view 
in default there 7*6 day views in a month view .
and have some icon show in the day view to display that depend on the record data.

I write the code in swift. and i test in iPod touch 5. 

about the performance . You should pay attention to the use of NSDate calculate, 
like NSDateFormatter .it can cause serious performances issues.

You can have a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project on Github with a calendar based on UICollectionView
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rsdayflow

I have used this component in a production project.
You can easily change it's appearance since every day is a uicollectionviewcell.

This project is based on https://github.com/evadne/DayFlow
that can be a good base to create what you need.

If you want to build your own calendar it can help you to find response to your questions: the code is easy to understand, and the implementation is in my opinion quite neat

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much is visualized in one screen. If it is one month i would have one month before and one month later. If it is only a day, one day before, one day later. Then use this infinite scrolling trick. There are many examples outside. I didn't read through the following link, but the pictures visualize the idea nicely:

[Building a Infinitely-Scrolling Gallery With a UICollectionView](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/07/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/)

Comment: kind of feels like UICollectionView isn't quite designed right no?   It's mean to allow one to leave the layout to the framework, yet it's built around pre-defining only a finite set of layout attributes, with no methods to support scrolling beyond the initial set calculated no.  I mean you kind of have to still manually manage creation/deletion of cell data/layout information really due to this...or am I missing something.